# GIF Photoshop images are not clear after saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, visual-artifacts

I have created an image in Photoshop with three layers but after saving as a GIF and if I view it in Browser, the animation is dotted and not clear. 
If anybody has some idea why please share.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

GIFs have a limited 256 colour palette (8 bit). To simulate more colours, [Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) is used. Usually it results in better images.

If there is an option for dithering, turn it off. Otherwise copy your high color image into clipboard, create an 8 bit image and paste it there, then save it as GIF.